# Spliterator for immutable linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, java-8, singly-linked-list, spliterator

This is a classic implementation of an immutable linked list:

```
public abstract class List<A> implements Iterable<A> {
    private static final List NIL = new Nil();

    public abstract A head();
    public abstract List<A> tail();
    public List<A> cons(A a) { return new Cons<>(a, this); }

    public static <A> List<A> nil() { return NIL; }

    @Override
    public Iterator<A> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<A>() {
            private List<A> list = List.this;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return list != NIL;
            }

            @Override
            public A next() {
                A n = list.head();
                list = list.tail();
                return n;
            }
        };
    }

    public Stream<A> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }

    public Stream<A> parallelStream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), true);
    }
}

class Nil extends List {
    @Override public Object head() { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
    @Override public List tail() { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
}

class Cons<A> extends List<A> {
    private final A head;
    private final List<A> tail;

    Cons(A head, List<A> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    @Override public A head() { return head; }
    @Override public List<A> tail() { return tail; }
}
```

The default implementation of `spliterator()` does not support efficient parallelizing:

```
List<Integer> list = List.<Integer> nil().cons(3).cons(2).cons(1);

list.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println(i);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

This will print `1, 2, 3` sequentially.

How to implement `spliterator()` to support efficient parallelizing?

Comment: Consider this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569040/readerlines-parallelizes-badly-due-to-nonconfigurable-batch-size-policy-in-it

Comment: Instead of a List you could implement a SkipList data structure, those are easier to parallelize.

Comment: How much work do you plan to do per element? Only if it's heavier than 100 µs does it make sense to split down to single elements.

Comment: You are asking how to use a data structure, which is bad for a large number of elements in general, together with a feature which is only relevant for a large number of element anyway. Don’t be surprised that this doesn’t really pay off. Linked lists are good in a class room but I never saw any real life use case for them in practice.

Comment: @Holger I'm not sure how parallellism is related to the number of elements in the collection. What if I want to process 3 heavy tasks in parallel?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: if you want to process 3 heavy tasks in parallel, there is nothing wrong with that. But since frameworks cannot predict how heavy particular tasks are, they don’t assume them to be outrageously heavy. That’s why the default spliterator of your linked list doesn’t run in parallel for three elements. It assumes that the overhead of buffering the elements of your sequential iterator doesn’t pay off unless you have at least thousands of elements. You can implement a spliterator with a different strategy but a spliterator still doesn’t know how expensive the per-element task will be…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spliterators which cannot report even the estimated size (which is default implementation for `Iterable`) are poorly split by parallel pipeline. You can fix this issue if you track the size of the `List`. In your case it's not very hard to track the exact size:

```
public abstract class List<A> implements Iterable<A> {
    ...
    public abstract long size();

    @Override
    public Spliterator<A> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), size(), Spliterator.ORDERED);
    }
}

class Nil extends List {
    ...
    public long size() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Cons<A> extends List<A> {
    ...
    private final long size;

    Cons(A head, List<A> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
        this.size = tail.size()+1;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

After that parallelization would work better. Note that it's still poor man parallelization, because you cannot quickly jump to the middle of the list, but in many cases it will provide a reasonable speed-up.

Also note that it's better to explicitly specify the `Spliterator.ORDERED` characteristic. Otherwise the order may be ignored in parallel stream operations even if it's explicitly requested (for example, by `forEachOrdered()` terminal operation).

Answer (score 1):

You might use some algorithm with *interleaving* - e.g., counting the elements and using remainder after integer division. That could split the elements for parallel iteration.

You could also iterate once before the iterator is even constructed, to split the list into *intervals*, but that would beat the purpose of stream - e.g. if you use it for `anyMatch`, it will slow you a lot.

There is no *really efficient* way to split a linked list (in less than linear time), unless you create your own implementation of linked list that has some additional information.

**Edit:** Oh wait - you only implement `Iterable`. That is quite limiting, you have to come up with an algorithm that only has one pass. That means, the splitting itself won't be parallel at all, so you might as well enforce your parallelism elsewhere in the process.