# Java 8 read from an input stream to an output stream, while aggregating items

Tags: java, stream, java-8, java-stream

The practical task is being able to return a Stream by reading from a file, but doing so without loading the whole file (or the parsed collection) entirely in memory. The purpose for that stream may be determined later -- e.g. save to DB. The developer would have a handle to a deserialized stream (instead of a deserialized collection).

The issue with that is that there is no guarantee that one line from the file equals one MyEntity object (in which case I could have used this article: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/05/parsing-file-with-stream-api-in-java-8.html)

In general, one may find a situation where, provided an input stream, one needs to return an output stream constructed by mapping a variable number of input stream items to one output stream item.

So, my solution so far is by using a Supplier, like this:

```
public class Parser{

    public Stream<MyEntity> parse(final InputStream stream) {
        return Stream.generate(new AggregatingSupplier(stream));
    }
    private class AggregatingSupplier implements Supplier<MyEntity> {

        private final Scanner r;

        public AggregatingSupplier(final InputStream source) {
            this.r= new Scanner(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MyEntity get() {
            MyEntity re=new MyEntity();
            while (r.hasNextLine() &&!re.isComplete()){
                String line=r.nextLine();
                // ... do some processing
            }
            return re;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the stream obtained with Stream.generate is infinite. There is no stop condition. Throwing an exception works (somewhat). Or choosing a completely different (classical) approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a `Supplier` consider implementing your custom `Spliterator`. It's less daunting than it may look at first (by inspecting the `Spliterator` interface) because there is the `Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator` base class which makes it quite easy: just provide `tryAdvance()`, which will look basically the same as what you have now in `Supplier`.

The halting condition becomes simple: just let `tryAdvance()` return `false`.

Comment: and then use [StreamSupport.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to return it. Thanks, I'll give it a try. I wonder if the stream will remain lazy though. I'll do some testing and post back.

Comment: Sure it will---all streams are backed by a Spliterator and you'll get the exact same behavior with yours. You can also look into [my other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569040/readerlines-parallelizes-badly-due-to-nonconfigurable-batch-size-policy-in-it) if you're interested in parallelization.

Answer (score 2):

Using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library this might be somewhat simpler as it has the killer feature to partially reduce the stream combining several adjacent elements based on the specified condition. For example, you can do the following:

```
public Stream<MyEntity> parse(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    return StreamEx.ofLines(new InputStreamReader(stream))
                   .groupRuns((a, b) -> !isEndOfEntry(a))
                   .map(strings -> createMyEntityFromListOfStrings(strings));
}
```

The [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) method accepts the `BiPredicate` which is applied to the pair of adjacent lines and should return true if these lines are part of the same group. If you have specific marker which marks the last line of the entry, you can test the first string (`a`) for this. Alternatively if it's easier to detect the start of the new entry, you can check the string `b`. This method creates `StreamEx<List<String>>` which elements are lists of grouped strings, so you can process them to create your `MyEntity` object. If you don't like to have an intermediate `List`, you can write the `Collector` which creates your `MyEntity` and use the [`collapse(BiPredicate, Collector)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#collapse-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) method which accepts the same `BiPredicate` and any `Collector` to perform the partial reduction.