# How to conditionally modify a Map in Java 8 stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to modify a `Map`'s keys based on conditional logic and struggling. I'm new to Java 8 streams API. Let's say I have a map like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("PLACEHOLDER", "some_data1");
map.put("Google", "some_data2");
map.put("Facebook", "some_data3");
map.put("Microsoft", "some_data4");
```

When I would like to do is find the references of `PLACEHOLDER` and conditionally change that key to something else based on a boolean condition. I feel like it should be *something* like the below, but this doesn't even compile of course.

```
boolean condition = foo();

map = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> "PLACEHOLDER".equals(entry.getKey()))
        .map(key -> {
            if (condition) {
                return "Apple";
            } else {
                return "Netflix";
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854574/java-8-streams-conditional-processing) which kind of makes me think maybe I can't do this with Java 8 stream APIs. Hopefully someone better at this than me knows how to do this. [Ideone link](https://ideone.com/Yt1SeL) if you want to play with it.

Comment: Can you please clarify more, do you want to change the key or the value?

Comment: @YCF_L the key, which makes things a little weirder.

Comment: Could you please edit your question in that case - "_... and conditionally change it's value to something else_" is what was causing confusion. Normally that would mean "change the value associated with that key".

Comment: Let us know if you solved your problem. If you did, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer, or add your own answer explaining how you solved it.

Answer (score 5):

You've filtered out all elements that *aren't* `PLACEHOLDER`. You need to add that filter logic to your `map` operation:

```
final Map<String, String> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> {
            if (!e.getKey().equals("PLACEHOLDER")) {
                return e;
            }
            if (condition) {
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>("Apple", e.getValue());
            }
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>("Netflix", e.getValue());
        }).collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

---

But as you are guaranteed to only have a single instance of `PLACEHOLDER` in the `Map`, you can just do

```
String placeholderData = input.remove("PLACEHOLDER");
if (placeholderData != null) {
    input.put(condition ? "Apple" : "Netflix", placeholderData);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do it using `Stream`s, you just need to move the conditional logic to the collection phase, like that:

```
boolean condition = true;
map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> mapKey(entry.getKey(), condition), Map.Entry::getValue
));
```

where:

```
private static String mapKey(String key, boolean condition) {
    if (!"PLACEHOLDER".equals(key)) {
        return key;
    }
    if (condition) {
        return "Apple";
    } else {
        return "Netflix";
    }
}
```

However, the second part of [Boris the Spider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459558/2032415) using `Map.remove` and `Map.put` seems the best way to go.

Comment: I think your approach of doing the magic in the key mapping function is neater than my `map` based approach.