# Optimize load of file processing

Tags: java, performance, io, kotlin, jvm

I'm working on large text files (multiple GB) and I need to convert this to a JSON structure. Of course I cannot load this into memory so I'm streaming it.

My current way is to read the input file line by line using a `BufferedReader` and calling `readLine()`. The first thing is, It is not very performant. So, how can I improve the read speed?

The other thing is now can I write the data fast out, preferred in the right order? -> Multithreading?

Right now my program is running for a while, with just a high load one a single CPU and a nice small memory usage (~77MB, while processing a 12GB file) and a low IO load of 11MB/s which is a disk usage of about 2-5%.

I'm storing my data on the drive. I access the data via this Iterator:

```
private class FileLineIterator(file: File) : MutableIterator<String> {
    private val reader = file.bufferedReader()

    override fun hasNext() = reader.ready()

    override fun next(): String = reader.readLine()

    override fun remove() {
        NotImplementedError("Not supported in this mode")
    }
}
```

My usage looks like this:

```
val out = File("test.txt").outputStream()
val files = File("cache/").listFiles { _, name -> name.endsWith(".cache") }
out.write(prefix)
files.forEach { file ->
    val lines = FileLineIterator(file)
    val isFirstLine = true
    lines.forEachIndexed { index, line ->
        if(isFirstLine) {
            isFirstLine = false
        } else {
            out.write(','.toInt())
        }
        out.write(lineStart)
        out.write(line.toByteArray())
        out.write('"'.toInt())
    }
}
out.write(suffix)
out.close()
```

I would be interested in your ideas to speed up this read/write process.

Comment: For parallelization you should use java.util. stream and to get good perf from an unbounded stream check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569040/readerlines-parallelizes-badly-due-to-nonconfigurable-batch-size-policy-in-it/22575506#22575506).

Comment: Well okay I'll pull out more implementation details: I am holding a list of ints (in fact hashcodes) and check if it is in the list before adding an element to the hashset. I'm also writing the hashes on my drive so I can guess the element count of the text file by dividing the hash file size by the size of an int. When the list become bigger then a threshold I start writing everything on the drive. I hope that helps somehow...

Comment: A few GB of text only needs a 2-3x this in memory. e.g. if you have a 32 GB machine you could hold a 10 GB file in memory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176207/discussion-on-question-by-rekire-optimize-load-of-file-processing).

Comment: FYI: I just kept my solution it works for me. The case where I created so large files were on wrong assumptions and wrong information.