# If on a java parallel stream forEach is called by n threads does it mean that at a time n items are read for processing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, nio, parallel.foreach

So, I wanted to process a file line by line in parallel, and as each line processing is independent I don't need it to be sequential. Also file is big so I don't want to read the full file into memory initially.
So I was thinking if I call java NIO `File.lines()` and then process the resulting stream using n threads. Does it mean that only n lines will be read into the memory and processed?
I was thinking that this approach should be similar to a bucket processing approach where a thread reads n lines into a blocking queue, whereas a pool of threads processes those read lines in parallel.

Comment: Heavily depends on the file size (“big” is very unspecific and I’ve encountered very different ideas of what “big” is), the Java version, and some other environmental aspects.

Comment: @Holger I wanted to check more about whether a file stream generated using NIO Files.lines, when consumed using forEach() would only load a single line into the memory at a time? The java version is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important information first; the stream returned by `Files.lines()` does not load the entire file into the memory.

The amount of data held in memory at the same time, is implementation dependent and will unavoidably raise when turning on parallel processing, but it does not depend on the file size (unless it’s a rather small file).

You may simply *try* whether it works for your case and ignore the details below.

---

In the reference implementation of Java 8, `Files.lines()` does just delegate to [`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines()). The only difference is that a close handler is installed, so closing the stream will close the underlying `BufferedReader`. So there are two buffers involved, one for the source data of the charset conversion and the one inside the `BufferedReader` to identify the line boundaries before creating the line strings and passing them to the stream.

Since the size of these buffers does not depend on the size of the file, they are nothing to worry about when processing large files.

But as discussed in [Reader#lines() parallelizes badly due to nonconfigurable batch size policy in its spliterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22569040/2711488) Java 8’s implementation of this stream is not well suited to parallel processing. It inherits a fallback splitting strategy which buffers at least 1024 elements and raises this chunk size by 1024 on each split operation, up to 33554432 elements per chunk. In case of a stream of lines, these are the number of lines which may exist in memory at a time, *per thread*. Depending on what a “large file” means to you, it may boil down to having the entire file in memory in the worst case or not the entire file but still too much for your use case.

This has been addressed by [JDK-8072773, (fs) Files.lines needs a better splitting implementation for stream source](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072773) for JDK 9. But it’s worth noting that the request has been implemented *literally*.

Instead of taking the opportunity to improve `BufferedReader.lines()` to implement a `Spliterator` directly, most of the code has not been touched at all. Instead `Files.lines` just got a better splitting implementation and otherwise runs through the same inefficient code paths.

If the preconditions are fulfilled (the `Path` is on the default filesystem, the charset is one of the supported, and the file can be mapped as a single `ByteBuffer`), a special spliterator is created which does memory mapping and identifies potential split positions, i.e. line breaks, within that `ByteBuffer`. But once the initial splitting is done, despite there’s a `ByteBuffer` representing the chunk and knowledge about how to identify line breaks in it, the code create a new `BufferedReader` for the chunk, to do the same inefficient decoding and streaming via wrapped `Iterator` as before, but now for every chunk of work.

So while this is an improvement, it has the following shortcomings:

- While it is an optimization specifically for *large* files, it stops being effective with files larger than 2 GiB
- It only works for the default filesystem and certain charsets (currently UTF-8, ISO-LATIN-1, and US-ASCII)
- If the workload is unbalanced, e.g. you have filter matching one half of the file, followed by the actual expensive work, so the initial splitting is not enough to give every CPU core some work, the parallel performance will suffer, as the new spliterators do not support splitting after the traversal started, not even the buffer array variant of `BufferedReader`
- While the original approach has a single `BufferedReader` with the two buffers mentioned above, you now have a `BufferedReader` for every chunk of work.

It’s still as said at the beginning, `Files.lines()` does not load the entire file into the memory. And your use case might benefit from these improvements. But it depends on the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Though I am still a bit confused about how the `trySplit` works, especially the line loading. Seems it's loading the buffer directly. So if my understanding is correct, then using 2 threads to process the `Files.lines` stream in parallell then it will directly load 1024 + (1024 +1024) lines into memory initially?

Comment: Or I am understanding it wrong and it's only the positions where it will split at. The lines are loaded one by one when using forEach. So if just printing the line content and not collecting them, then at a time each processing thread will have only one line?

Comment: You’re asking about Java 8’s behavior? A single split will load 1024 lines, so one spliterator operates on the array of those 1024 lines, the other behaves like a sequential one, just reading from the file. But the implementation will perform *more splits than threads*, so a thread completing its work can pick up new one (not every spliterator supports splitting after the traversal started, JDK 9+ `Files.lines()` is such an example). Expect something like #threads×3 splits. Subsequent splits prefer the file based spliterator with the unknown size, reading 2048, then 3072, then 4096, and so on.