# How do you do a parallel fold on a Kotlin sequence?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, fold

As an exercise to help me learn Kotlin, I am writing an application in which I have a large sequence of objects, and I want to find the "best" one according to a set of criteria, for which the obvious way is to use a fold.

I have done the same thing in other languages, notably Java and Haskell, and in both of those I can achieve a big improvement in performance by doing a parallel fold - that is, splitting the sequence into chunks, folding each chunk separately and in parallel, and then combining the results.

In Java (assuming that `objs` is a `Stream` containing the objects I want to fold), this is as simple as:

```java
objs.parallel().reduce(this::findBetter);
```

and the chunking and parallel folds are then handled for me.

I can't work out how to do this in Kotlin. I know that splitting the sequence into a sequence of chunks is easy, using the `chunked` method, and I can then convert that sequence to a flow of chunks, and I then thought that the next stage would be to map each chunk in the flow to the result of asynchronously folding the chunk; then I could fold the flow of intermediate results to get my final result. But everything I've tried seems to fail to compile at some point.

Is this a good approach, and if so how could it be coded - in particular the bit about asynchronously folding the chunk?

Comment: Java Paralllel Streams only work well for collections of known size that support random access, which means that each element can be independently materialized or is already materialized. Is that true for your case? It dramatically influences how you would reimplement this in Kotlin.

Comment: No, neither is true. But a Java parallel stream works perfectly well. In a typical example, the total time taken to arrive at a solution (which involves building the stream and then folding it) is about 3.5 seconds if the stream is not converted to a parallel stream before folding, and about 1.5 seconds if it is.

Comment: I see, a definite improvement, but still a factor of just 2.3, whereas it probably has many more CPU cores at disposal. With a sized, random-accesss stream, it will split it into just as many parts as there are CPU cores, and evaluate each with very little overhead. For a stream of unknown size, it will apply a heuristic where it uses an arithmetic progression of chunk sizes, in increments of 1024, and it's hardcoded. What's your core count, and what's the collection size?

Comment: In case you'll find this interesting to explore, a while back I wrote some Java Stream code that lets you specify the chunk size yourself. You can try specifying a size of (collection size)/(core count) to see if it makes a difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569040/readerlines-parallelizes-badly-due-to-nonconfigurable-batch-size-policy-in-it

Comment: Thank you for your responses. At the moment I am more interested in improving the performance of my Kotlin solution, but maybe in future I will take up your suggestions for the Java one.

Comment: That's a side point, anyway. The main point is, your Java performance isn't a high enough target to aim for. You should see how many cores you have, and aim for that multiple of speedup.

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually more tricky than it seems. It sounds like a simple request for a feature which should be just there and just works. However, both sequences and flows are by design sequential and ordered. Concurrent processing isn't their goal and they don't support such feature. I believe there are plans to provide it for flows, but we are not there yet.

Also, we need to be aware adding such feature is not that straightforward as there is not a single way to do this. If the sequence/flow is ordered, should we entirely ignore ordering for parallel processing or do we need to provide some ordering guarantees? How should we split the work between workers? How to schedule concurrent tasks: threads, executors, coroutines? What's the expected level of concurrency? Etc.

Let's assume we would like to use coroutines, we ignore ordering entirely and we chunk the data as you said. The simplest solution would be based on collections - as you said, we need to chunk the data, process each chunk asynchronously, then join:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Iterable<T>.parallelReduce(chunkSize: Int, operation: (T, T) -> T): T = coroutineScope {
    chunked(chunkSize)
        .map { async { it.reduce(operation) } }
        .awaitAll()
        .reduce(operation)
}
```

We can use this with a sequence by: `seq.asIterable().parallelReduce(...)`. Of course, this solution consumes the whole sequence at an initial step. If the sequence is very large and we can't keep all items in the memory, we need another solution.

We can convert the sequence to a flow. Flow is pretty similar to a sequence, but it allows to use coroutines in its operators and also, it provides a way to split the pipeline into two concurrent pipelines by placing a [buffer()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) in the middle:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Sequence<T>.parallelReduce(chunkSize: Int, concurrency: Int, operation: (T, T) -> T): T = coroutineScope {
    require(concurrency >= 2)
    chunked(chunkSize).asFlow()
        .map { async { it.reduce(operation) } }
        .buffer(concurrency - 2) // buffer of 0 already provides concurrency of 2
        .map { it.await() }
        .reduce(operation)
}
```

Essentially, it works in a similar way to the first example, but instead of scheduling all chunks straight away, it launches only a limited number of tasks at a time. Please be aware this solution still consumes results sequentially, not concurrently. That means if the first chunk takes much longer than others, then after subsequent chunks are finished, we won't consume their results and won't start another chunk until the first chunk unblocks the whole pipeline.

Also, it feels a little strange we use flows like this. They were designed more for inter-components communication, not as a concurrency tool. It feels strange we launch coroutines in the `flow.map()`. Alternatively, we can do it entirely manually by using a channel and launching worker coroutines:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Sequence<T>.parallelReduce(chunkSize: Int, concurrency: Int, operation: (T, T) -> T): T = coroutineScope {
    val inputsChannel = produce { chunked(chunkSize).forEach { send(it) } }
    val resultsChannel = Channel<T>()
    val result = async {
        var acc = resultsChannel.receive()
        for (item in resultsChannel) {
            acc = operation(acc, item)
        }
        acc
    }
    coroutineScope {
        repeat(concurrency) {
            launch {
                for (inputs in inputsChannel) {
                    resultsChannel.send(inputs.reduce(operation))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    resultsChannel.close()
    result.await()
}
```

This solution both processes and consumes results concurrently, so it doesn't have the drawback mentioned above.

As a bonus: what I said about flows not supporting concurrent processing is not entirely true. There is one operator which actually provides concurrent processing: [flatMapMerge()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html). It feels it doesn't fit the whole API very well, like it was added by accident. Anyway, it allows to use concurrent processing very easily:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Sequence<T>.parallelReduce(chunkSize: Int, concurrency: Int, operation: (T, T) -> T): T = coroutineScope {
    chunked(chunkSize).asFlow()
        .flatMapMerge(concurrency) {
            flow { emit(it.reduce(operation)) }
        }
        .reduce(operation)
}
```

I consider this to be a trick of some sort. It is not very clear what this code does and especially: how it does it. But it works, it requires minimal code and I believe it schedules processing optimally.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post your very detailed answer. I've tried various of your suggestions, and as far as I can see none of them actually improve the performance of my algorithm. It takes around 10 seconds to arrive at a typical solution, irrespective of whether I fold the sequence sequentially or in parallel.

Comment: I tested all solutions before posting and they decreased the time as expected: concurrency of 2 resulted in ~1/2 time, concurrency=4 resulted in 1/4 time, etc.. https://pl.kotl.in/stgby97Lo 100 items, 100ms per item, concurrency=2 - it takes ~5s. How did you test it? Did you maybe use `runBlocking()`? If yes, please be aware by default `runBlocking()` uses a single thread.

Comment: You're right, I did use `runBlocking()` so that is probably it. What is the alternative?

Comment: This is not exactly caused by using `runBlocking()`, but by using its default dispatcher. You can simply switch to another one: `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }`. Please be aware `runBlocking()` is generally discouraged for other reasons, but this is a separate discussion.

Comment: I changed to `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default)`, but it still doesn't seem to make any difference to the run time.

Comment: If it would help, the code is in this repo: https://github.com/hicksjduk/countdown-kotlin.

Comment: Sorry, but analyzing the code in your project is far from the scope of this question. Example in the Kotlin Playground above suggests these solutions in fact work as expected. How do you know `comparer()` is a bottleneck in your case? It looks like just a few math operations, similar to all other operations that you do sequentially. Did you mean to add concurrency to all operations, even before the fold?